# Damping gets better, but overshoot increases. How can I explain it?

Tags: control, transfer-function, step-response

I have three transfer functions as below

[image]

The pole-zero plot and the step response of the transfer functions are given as

[image]

[image]

It makes sense to me that G3 has a better damping than G2 and G2 has a better damping than G1 as both the pole-zero plot and step response suggest. But shouldn't the overshoot also decrease as the damping factor increases according to the following formula from second-order system response:

[image]
where zeta is the damping factor.

Do you think it is the effect of the zero? Can I say that when the dominant poles is getting closer to the zero, it somewhat cancels the effect of that pole and overshoot increases? Can it be mathematically explained?

EDIT: Here is the zoomed-in view of the dominant real pole. It doesn't move significantly as you see.

[image]

Comment: What is the overall gain? Is it normalized between cases? Where is the real pole moving?

Comment: What do you mean by overall gain? There is no normalization involved. I just plotted the poles and zeros of the three transfer functions given and plotted their step response using the step() command in MATLAB. I added a zoomed-in view of the real pole trajectory, which doesn't move significantly in the three cases.

Comment: If I take one system and measure its impulse response, and *the identical system times an ideal gain of 10* and measure its impulse response -- has its overshoot increased by 900%?